# looping over variables of heterogeneous type

Tags: c++, c++17

These snippets are nothing special, but they remind us to sometimes loop without a `for` or a `while` loop. It is even possible to iterate over `struct` members in a similar manner.

```
template <typename ...A>
constexpr auto all_loop(A&& ...a) noexcept
{
  return [&](auto const f) noexcept(noexcept(
    (f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)), ...)))
    {
      (f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)), ...);
    };
}

template <typename ...A>
constexpr auto cond_loop(A&& ...a) noexcept
{
  return [&](auto const f) noexcept(noexcept(
    (f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)), ...)))
    {
      return (f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)) || ...);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
all_loop(1, 2, 3, false, true, nullptr)([](auto&& v) { std::cout << v << std::endl; });
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/kFnaNn1vPoS0lF4F

Answer (score 2):

## No need to return a lambda

I don't see the need for returning a lambda which you then have to invoke. Why not pass the function as the first parameter, similar to [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) and [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)? I would rewrite `all_loop()` like so:

```
template <typename F, typename ...A>
constexpr void invoke_all(F f, A&& ...a)
noexcept(noexcept((f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)), ...)))
{
     (f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)), ...);
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
invoke_all([](auto&& v){std::cout << v << '\n';}, 1, 2, 3, false, true, nullptr);
```

If you really need to have it as a lambda, the caller can still do that themselves:

```
auto curried = [](auto const f){invoke_all(f, 1, 2, 3, false, true, nullptr);};
curried([](auto&& v){std::cout << v << '\n';});
```

## Prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`

Use [`'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is normally not necessary and might impact performance.

## Making it "pipeable"

> I wanted to achieve something like `pipe(1, 2, 3) | f;`

You can do that as well, by creating a type that stores the values and overloads `operator|` to take any function. For example:

```
template <typename... A>
class pipe
{
    std::tuple<A...> a;
public:
    pipe(A&&... a): a{a...} {}
    auto operator|(auto&& f) {
        std::apply([&](auto&&... a){(f(a), ...);}, a);
    }
};
```

(I left all the `decltype`s and `std::forward`s as an excercise to the reader.) Then you can indeed write:

```
pipe(1, 2, 3, false, true, nullptr) | [](auto&& v) { std::cout << v << '\n'; };
```

But I would not use this, and rather stick to the idiomatic way of calling things in C++.

Comment: I wanted to separate the loop "body" from the arguments. We usually don't think of this sort of thing as "looping".

Comment: i.e. I wanted to achieve something like `pipe(1, 2, 3) | f;`

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to do that :) But this looks like you want the language to be different from what it is.

Comment: Pipe operator may become more idiomatic in the near future, given that it's now used to compose views in the Ranges library.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `std::tuple<A&&...> a;` ?

Comment: @TobySpeight Hm, you might be right. But I don't think the Ranges library will support containers of heterogeneous types? At least not in the near future?

Comment: @user1095108 Yes, and then you also need to add the perfect forwarding. That's why I said I left it as an excercise. I think that should not be a problem, you did this correctly in your code!

Comment: Oh, I wasn't claiming that!  Only saying that like we got used to `<<` and `>>` not just being bit-shift but also streaming back in the 1980s, and that other libraries have followed that lead, we might start to see use of `|` as a composition operator more widely, following its use in Ranges.  I'm not really advocating that in 2021, though - just musing on the way idioms can change.

Comment: if `std::tuple` were more inspired, we could just do `std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2, 3) | f`.